# Dovecot enters a failed state with exit code error

Tags: dovecot, ssl-certificate-errors

I am having problems with dovecot on a debian 9 system running webmin/virtualmin.

After an update, it seems that the renewal of a domain SSL certificate caused at least one  client domain to use the wrong domain ssl certificate for email...the all my problems started.

```
systemctl status dovecot.service returns...

    May 08 13:42:31 server1.domain.com.au doveadm[6252]: Fatal: Dovecot is not running (read from /var/run/dovecot/master.pid)
May 08 13:42:31 server1.domain.com.au systemd[1]: dovecot.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=75
May 08 13:42:31 server1.domain.com.au systemd[1]: dovecot.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 08 13:42:31 server1.domain.com.au systemd[1]: dovecot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have tried to restart but i get errors.

So i did the following ps aux | grep dovecot

```
    dovenull  2313  0.0  0.1  21760  5832 ?        S    14:13   0:00 dovecot/imap-login
secreta+  2315  0.0  0.0  23876  3868 ?        S    14:13   0:00 dovecot/imap
dovenull  4936  0.0  0.1  21760  5636 ?        S    14:51   0:00 dovecot/imap-login
dovenull  4938  0.0  0.1  21760  5712 ?        S    14:51   0:00 dovecot/imap-login
members+  4952  0.0  0.1  23880  4476 ?        S    14:51   0:00 dovecot/imap
adamjed+  4953  0.0  0.1  23868  4572 ?        S    14:51   0:00 dovecot/imap
dovenull  5877  0.0  0.1  21748  5968 ?        S    14:53   0:00 dovecot/imap-login
contact+  6029  0.0  0.0  23536  3920 ?        S    14:53   0:00 dovecot/imap
root      6253  0.0  0.0  18132  2548 ?        Ss   13:42   0:00 /usr/sbin/dovecot
dovecot   6254  0.0  0.0   9492   944 ?        S    13:42   0:00 dovecot/anvil
root      6255  0.0  0.0   9624  2324 ?        S    13:42   0:00 dovecot/log
root      6257  0.0  0.3  29768 12660 ?        S    13:42   0:00 dovecot/config
liaison+  8815  0.0  0.1  23916  4380 ?        S    13:44   0:00 dovecot/imap
preside+ 10156  0.0  0.0  23896  3884 ?        S    14:21   0:00 dovecot/imap
dovenull 13538  0.0  0.1  21748  5636 ?        S    14:55   0:00 dovecot/imap-login
ajecrea+ 13549  0.0  0.1  23892  4468 ?        S    14:55   0:00 dovecot/imap
preside+ 14016  0.0  0.1  24488  4960 ?        S    14:25   0:00 dovecot/imap
dovecot  15172  0.0  0.0  20520  2788 ?        S    14:57   0:00 dovecot/auth
root     19500  0.0  0.0   4276   716 ?        S    15:00   0:00 sh -c (ps aux | grep dovecot) 2>&1
root     19501  0.0  0.0   4276    88 ?        S    15:00   0:00 sh -c (ps aux | grep dovecot) 2>&1
root     19503  0.0  0.0  11104   928 ?        S    15:00   0:00 grep dovecot
dovenull 20675  0.0  0.1  21748  5624 ?        S    14:32   0:00 dovecot/imap-login
contact+ 20686  0.0  0.1  23948  4516 ?        S    14:32   0:00 dovecot/imap
dovenull 23780  0.0  0.1  21748  5636 ?        S    14:34   0:00 dovecot/imap-login
contact+ 23782  0.0  0.1  24592  5160 ?        S    14:34   0:00 dovecot/imap
```

After forcing dovecot to completely shutdown i then run systemctl restart dovecot

systemctl status dovecot returns the following after a successful dovecot restart

```
   # ps aux | grep dovecot
root     31916  0.0  0.0  18000  2520 ?        Ss   15:39   0:00 /usr/sbin/dovecot
dovecot  31917  0.0  0.0   9492   988 ?        S    15:39   0:00 dovecot/anvil
root     31918  0.0  0.0   9624  2284 ?        S    15:39   0:00 dovecot/log
root     31921  0.0  0.1  25176  7136 ?        S    15:39   0:00 dovecot/config
dovecot  32001  0.0  0.0  20520  2524 ?        S    15:39   0:00 dovecot/auth
root     32002  0.0  0.0  33204  3768 ?        S    15:39   0:00 dovecot/auth -w
root     32166  0.0  0.0   4276   748 ?        S    15:40   0:00 sh -c (ps aux | grep dovecot) 2>&1
root     32167  0.0  0.0   4276    88 ?        S    15:40   0:00 sh -c (ps aux | grep dovecot) 2>&1
root     32169  0.0  0.0  11104   920 ?        S    15:40   0:00 grep dovecot
```

However, after users try to reconnect their email client apps with my mail server, dovecot eventually stops working again (did this after about 30 mins last time).

I am now at a mental blank and need help.

Answer (score 0):

is there no one with a solution to this?
I am still having problems...here is the latest mail log...i dont understand why these errors are shutting down the dovecot status monitor on my debeian server.

> can someone got through this error log and explain to me exactly why these particular errors are appearing.
>   (the ipaddress is left as is in the error log…it is not a known ipaddress to me)

May 20 14:16:02 server1 dovecot: anvil: Fatal: master: service(anvil): child 1941 killed with signal 9
May 20 14:16:12 server1 dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: master: service(imap-login): child 25826 killed with signal 9
May 20 14:16:12 server1 dovecot: anvil: Error: connect limit: disconnection for unknown pid 25828 + ident imap/103.129.156.70/operations@domain1.com
May 20 14:16:20 server1 dovecot: auth: Error: net_connect_unix(anvil-auth-penalty) failed: Permission denied
May 20 14:16:20 server1 dovecot: auth: Error: auth worker: Aborted PASSV request for operations@domain1.com: Shutting down
May 20 14:16:26 server1 dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: master: service(imap-login): child 4394 killed with signal 9
May 20 14:16:26 server1 dovecot: anvil: Error: connect limit: disconnection for unknown pid 4395 + ident imap/52.125.136.93/contact@domain3.com
May 20 14:16:37 server1 dovecot: anvil: Error: connect limit: disconnection for unknown pid 9749 + ident imap/52.125.130.11/secretary@domain1.com
May 20 14:16:37 server1 dovecot: imap-login: Fatal: master: service(imap-login): child 9748 killed with signal 9
May 20 14:16:45 server1 dovecot: anvil: Error: connect limit: disconnection for unknown pid 28250 + ident imap/52.125.136.93/contact@domain3.com
May 20 14:17:18 server1 dovecot: master: Fatal: Dovecot is already running? Socket already exists: /var/run/dovecot/login/login
May 20 14:18:06 server1 dovecot: anvil: Error: connect limit: disconnection for unknown pid 7074 + ident imap/52.125.130.11/secretary@domain1.com
May 20 14:19:01 server1 dovecot: anvil: Error: connect limit: disconnection for unknown pid 15213 + ident imap/120.146.145.157/adamjedgar@domain2.com
May 20 14:19:16 server1 dovecot: anvil: Error: connect limit: disconnection for unknown pid 25509 + ident imap/1.129.106.62/contact@domain3.com
May 20 16:34:31 server1 dovecot: master: Error: unlink(/var/run/dovecot/master.pid) failed: No such file or directory (in main.c:558)
May 21 01:19:36 server1 dovecot: master: Fatal: Dovecot is already running? Socket already exists: /var/run/dovecot/login/login
May 21 01:19:38 server1 dovecot: master: Fatal: Dovecot is already running? Socket already exists: /var/run/dovecot/login/login
May 21 01:19:40 server1 dovecot: master: Fatal: Dovecot is already running? Socket already exists: /var/run/dovecot/login/login
May 21 01:19:42 server1 dovecot: master: Fatal: Dovecot is already running? Socket already exists: /var/run/dovecot/login/login
May 21 06:33:31 server1 dovecot: master: Fatal: Dovecot is already running? Socket already exists: /var/run/dovecot/login/login